# nesting getElementById throwing error?

Tags: javascript

Why nesting getElementById throwing error? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4568y0n/2/) 
how can i solve this

```
var links = document.getElementById('menu').getElementById('one');
links.style.color="red";
```

but getElementsByTagName is working. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4568y0n/3/)

```
var links = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('li');
links[0].style.color="red";
```

please explain why?

helps will be appreciated

Comment: why are you using document.getElementById('menu').getElementById('one');
you can use document.getElementById('one') to retrieve the li tagged with one.

Comment: Since Id of an element must be unique you could just use `document.getElementById('one')`

Comment: It could throw an error if there is no element with id `menu`

Comment: If you want to make sure the descendant relationship is maintained and don't want the error then you could easily use `var links = document.querySelector('#menu #one');`

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Error: `document.getElementById(...).getElementById is not a function`

Comment: @arun P johny.. thanks i understand what is the issue. i just wanted to confirm the descendant relationship https://jsfiddle.net/n4568y0n/5/

Comment: In that case just use the `querySelector`

Comment: like https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n4568y0n/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `id` must be unique in a document. A tag name doesn't.

The only reason to try to call `getElementById` on a specific element is to find out if the element with the given ID exists as a descendant of a specific other element, but that wasn't something that was considered during the design of the API.

You can use `querySelector('#someId')` to achieve that.